# Non-standard scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I was wondering which properties of a Hilbert space depend on the scalar product defined (other than the usual one) I know for a fact that some inequalities such as Cauchy-Schwartz do not depend on the product (they are always true) . However, the definition of a  positive (semi-)definite matrix DOES depend on the nature of the inner product specified.

$\textbf{Context}:$
For ${x_1,...,x_n}$ vectors on $\mathbb C^m$, the Gram matrix is defined as
$$(G)_{ij} = \langle x_i|x_j\rangle$$
Is it true that G is positive semidefinite regardless of the scalar product used (i.e, any sesquilinear, positive definite form)? The proofs I have found involve writing $G $ as $ A^*A$ where A is the matrix whose columns are ${x_1,...,x_n}$ However, if we define another product, for example:
$$x\star y = \sum_{j=1}^{m}=j\bar x_jy_j$$
Then the matrix-vector mutiplication will no longer coincide with this product.

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: One can still write G in that form but now $A^*$ is the adjoint in the new inner product. Positive definiteness of $G $ (relative to the new inner product) follows from positive definiteness of the inner product itself.

Comment: So $A^*$ is not the conjugate transpose, thanks, that clears some things up